# I can add an overlay, but I can't remove it (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, overlay

This function adds an overlay with the following properties to the entire browser screen,

```
$('a.cell').click(function()    {
    $('<div id = "overlay" />').appendTo('body').fadeIn("slow");
});

#overlay
{
background-color: black;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
display: none;
z-index: 100;
opacity: 0.5;
}
```

And this function is supposed to remove it.

```
$('#overlay').click(function()  {
    $(this).fadeOut("slow").remove();
});
```

But it seems to do absolutely nothing and now my page is stuck with a black overly over it.  What's wrong with the removal?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that when you're adding the `click` handler, there isn't any overlay, so you're adding the handler to an empty set of elements.

To fix this, use the [live](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live#typefn) method to bind your handler to all elements that match `#overlay`, whenever they are created.

Also, `fadeOut` is not a blocking call, so it returns before the element finishes fading out.  Therefore, you're calling `remove` right after the element *starts* fading out.

To fix this, use `fadeOut`'s callback parameter to call `remove` after the animation finishes.

For example:

```
$('#overlay').live(function() { 
    $(this).fadeOut("slow", function() { $(this).remove(); });
});
```

Comment: Ah, I understand now.  I hadn't realized that the handlers were bound to the elements once the page is loaded.  I had thought of my JS as more of a library to look up once an even has occurred and then perform any functions that match what has happened on the page.  But now that I think about it, that would be incredibly slow and take up a lot of resources.  The way you described it fits much better than my way of thinking.  Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 3):

Here you go.  This should fix the problem and let the overlay fade out before removing it.

```
$('#overlay').live("click", function()  {
        $(this).fadeOut("slow", function() { $(this).remove() });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove should be in the callback to fadeout, like so:

```
$('#overlay').live('click', function()  {
    $(this).fadeOut("slow", function() {
       $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$('#overlay').live('click', function()  {
        $(this).fadeOut("slow").remove();
});
```

Comment: That works, although it seems to be removing the element before fading it out.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to use the [jquery.tools overlay plugin](http://jquerytools.org/demos/overlay/index.html). Your overlay will have a trigger (usually a button or link), but you can load or clear it with a javascript command, e.g.:

js:

```
var config = { closeOnClick:true, mask:{opacity:0.7, color:'#333', loadSpeed:1} }
$("#myTrigger").overlay(config); // add overlay functionality
$("#myTrigger").data("overlay").load(); // make overlay appear
$("#myTrigger").data("overlay").close(); // make overlay disappear
```

html:

```
<div id="myOverlay" style="display:none;">Be sure to set width and height css.</div>
<button id="myTrigger" rel="#myOverlay">show overlay</button>
```